# Field of rational functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, rational-functions

Let $K$ be a field with characteristic $p>0$ and $M=K(X,Y)$ the field of rational functions in 2 variables over $K$. We consider the subfield $L=K(X^p,Y^p)\subset M$.

Show that $[M:L]=p^2$.

I guess I need the property that $[K(x):K(x^n)]=n$, which we showed already. But I actually do not know how to use it here. I can not work well with that field in 2 variables..

Comment: Perhaps you are expected to use a similar proof technique to the proof of $[K(x):K(x^p)]=p$, rather than to use this result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that for some  field $J$ so that  $L \subset J \subset M$ you have that the degree of the extension $L \subset M$ is the product of the degrees of the extensions $L \subset J $ and $ J \subset M$.

Use this for example with $J=K(X^p,Y)$, applying the result you know twice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But one problem: The statement $[K(x):K(x^n)]=n$ is true if x is transcendental.(I forget to say that above). How we can use it for our case? Because polynomials with degree $\geq 1$ are transcendental over a given field K?

Comment: Note that $J$ can be seen as $K(X^p)(Y)$ and also as $K(Y)(X^p)$; and $K(X^p)$ and $K(Y)$ are fields.

Comment: Okay, so we can write $K(X^P)(Y^p)\subset K(X^p)(Y) \subset K(X)(Y)$. This is what you want to say? Fine :) .But still..can I say now that $Y^p$ is transcendental oder $Y$? If yes, why?

Comment: You do not need this. What you need is that $Y$ is transcendental over $K(X^P)$ and related facts; for the first step the $K(X^p)$ plays the role of $K$ in the result you use while Y plays the role of  X.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But how can I see this..this is still unclear for me i.e. why is Y transcendental over $K(X^p)$

Comment: This is because $X$ and $Y$ were assumed to be algebraically independent in the first place. Rational field with two variables means precisely that you adjoin two algebraically independent elements. This is basically the same as saying that $Y$ is transcendental over $K(X)$ and thus certainly over the smaller field $K(X^p)$. More down to earth. Can you ever have an expression $a_n(X)Y^n + ... + a_1(X)Y^1 + a_0(X)$ that equals $0$.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you for the afford. I want to extend the task: For $f \in M\L$ we consider $L(f)$.Show that $[L(f):L]=p$. If we consider the dimension formula: $p^2=[M:L]=[L(f):L] \cdot [M:L(f)]$, we see that $[L(f):L]=1$ or $p$ or $p^2$. 1 is impossible, because $f \notin L$. But why is $p^2$ impossible too? I.e why $M=L(f)$ can't be happen?

Comment: This is not true in general. It can happen when the characteristic of $K$ is $0$ (and I think but not sure also if the characteristic of $K$ is *not* $p$); in char 0 case the extension is definitely separable and the primitive element theorem implies that the extension is generated by a single element.  However, if the characteristic of $K$ is $p$, which could well be the case in your context, then consider $f^p$ and recall freshman's dream  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream to see that   $f^p$ in $L$ and thus $\deg f = p$. (Perhaps better ask new q if there are further things).

Comment: Are you sure that the statement is not true? Its an old task from the university. I post the complete task again: Let $K$ be a field with characteristic $p>0$ and $M=K(X,Y)$ the field of rational functions in two variables over $K$. We consider the subfield $L=K(X^p,Y^p) \subset M$. Show the following: For $f\in M$ \ $L$ holds: $[L(f):L]=p$

Comment: Sorry there was some misunderstanding. It is true for characteeristic p. I also said so in my comment. Note the part "However, if the characteristic is p..." I only had forgotten that this assumption was stated in your original question as for the original question it is not really necessary; it would work for any field. But for the follow up it is need and  Without it is not true. And, this is the first part of my comment.